# how to get a handle of link label using win32 APIs

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get a handle of an existing link label using win32 apis.
[image]

When I click on this link label, a child window opens. I want to get the handle of this link label so that I can perform a mouse operation of 'click' on this through SendMessage() API.

The attached picture highlights the linklabel in red.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: Learn the whole application tree using Spy++. Then use combination of FindWindow and EnumWindows API to find the button.

Comment: I have used FindWindow already to get the handle but it returns a NULL value. If I am not wrong, EnumWindows API is used to get the top level windows. But the handle, am trying to get is the control within the main window. I have used spy++ to get the classname and caption for FindWindow API. but it somehow returns NULL.

Comment: What about `EnumChildWindows` and when applicable, `GetDlgItem`?

Comment: I have added another image in my question where I am highlighting the control for which I need the handle in RED. I am able to get until its parent window which is highlighted in GREEN in my image 2. I have used FindWindowEx() to get until there. But for the one highlighted in RED, am unable to get the handle. Can you please help me find why this is failing at this level?

Comment: I am still stuck at this point...any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via COM, it's [available from Windows XP SP3 onwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx#RT_REQS).